# Using x and y-axis differ in log scaling in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I successfully plot my data using `ggplot()` in R. However, when I choose to have the y- and x- axis in log10 scaling, the first tick on the y-axis (0.01) is further apart for the intersection than the first tick on the x-axis (0.01). I need the x-axis to have the same "scaling" as the y-axis.

Here is my code. Also the data (use sep="\t"). And an image of how the graph looks for me. Im sorry the data is on an external link, I couldnt figure out how to give it to you as reproducible data otherwise!

```
FILE1 <- read.delim("example.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE)

EXAMPLE_PLOT <- ggplot(FILE1, aes_string(x = colnames(FILE1)[1], y = colnames(FILE1)[2])) + 
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  ggtitle("EXAMPLE_PLOT") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family="Calibri", color="black", 
                                  face="bold", size = 32, hjust=0)) +
  theme(plot.background= element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 1),
        axis.line.y  = element_line(color="black", size = 1))+
  theme(axis.ticks  = element_line(color="black", size = 1))+
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(0.3,"cm"))+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Calibri",
                                  color="black", size=17, face="bold"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Calibri", color="black",
                                   size=14, face="bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(family = "Calibri", color="black",
                                   size=14, face="bold"))+
  scale_x_log10(breaks=c(.01, .1, 1, 10, 100))+
  scale_y_log10(breaks=c(.01, .1, 1, 10, 100))+
  geom_smooth(method=lm)

EXAMPLE_PLOT
```

[THE DATA](http://www.file-upload.net/download-11685701/example.txt.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `limits` in the `scale_x_log10` and `scale_y_log10`:

[image]

```
FILE1 <- read.delim("example.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE)

EXAMPLE_PLOT <- ggplot(FILE1, aes_string(x = colnames(FILE1)[1], y = colnames(FILE1)[2])) + 
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  ggtitle("EXAMPLE_PLOT") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family="Calibri", color="black", 
                                  face="bold", size = 32, hjust=0)) +
  theme(plot.background= element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 1),
        axis.line.y  = element_line(color="black", size = 1))+
  theme(axis.ticks  = element_line(color="black", size = 1))+
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(0.3,"cm"))+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Calibri",
                                  color="black", size=17, face="bold"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Calibri", color="black",
                                   size=14, face="bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(family = "Calibri", color="black",
                                   size=14, face="bold"))+
  scale_x_log10(breaks=c(.01, .1, 1, 10, 100), limits = c(0.01,10))+
  scale_y_log10(breaks=c(.01, .1, 1, 10, 100), limits = c(0.01,10))+
  geom_smooth(method=lm) 

EXAMPLE_PLOT
```

Comment: It works if I write `limits = c(0.01,100)`, do not change your `breaks` (keep 100).

Comment: Thank you! It worked out! To people reading this now, I accidentally deleted my additional question. I wanted the scale to go all the way to 100.

Comment: Okay, now I cant save it with ggsave() anymore. It worked before this change. I get following error: Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  invalid font type

Comment: In my case, I still can use `ggsave()` with this plot. Be sure your last plot is `EXAMPLE_PLOT`, or use `ggsave("plot_.jpg",EXAMPLE_PLOT)`

Comment: EDIT: I fixed it by removing every 'family =' command and just leaving it to the default